# Laravel notification save in jobs table without implementing "ShouldQueue"

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification

Hi I am using this **pushnotification class** for broadcast but when I sent this notification to any user then it save in **jobs table** even i should not implement "**ShouldQueue**" to this notification.. in env I set **QUEUE_CONNECTION=database** because of other task like sent email etc.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;

class pushnotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database','broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'comment'=>'hi',
        ];
    }
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {

        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'comment'=>'hi',
            
        ]);
    }

    public function broadcastOn(){
        return ['status-liked'];
    }
}
```

i need it sent without running **php artisan queue:work** command bcz i didnot implements shouldqueue. Thanks for any help

Comment: Where do you trigger this event?

Comment: @KhangTran at this time make the test route and triger this                   Route::get('testpusher', function () {
    
    /*event(new App\Events\StatusLiked('Someone'));*/
    $user = User::find(2);
    $user->notify(new pushnotification(1,2,3));
    return "Event has been sent!";
});

Comment: @KhangTran      it will trigger and save in jobs table